# Scipy: Sparse matrix multiplication memory error

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I want to perform matrix multiplication between a sparse matrix and its transpose, (their are big matrices). Specifically, I have:

```
C = csc_matrix(...)
Ct = csc_matrix.transpose(C)
L = Ct*C
```

and shapes:

```
C.shape
(1791489, 28508141)
Ct.shape
(28508141, 1791489)
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\...\modularity.py", line 373, in <module>
    L = Ct*C

  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 480, in __mul__
    return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)

  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 518, in _mul_sparse_matrix
    indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.11 TiB for an array with shape (152087117507,) and data type int64
```

I cannot figure out why, why does it try to allocate memory for such a huge array ?

**Update:** Currently I am trying to do the multiplication in chunks like this

```
chunksize=1000
numiter = Ct.shape[0]//chunksize
blocks=[]
for i in range(numiter):
    A = Ct[i*chunksize:(i+1)*chunksize].dot(C)
    blocks.append(A)
```

But I get:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 217. MiB for an array with shape (57012620,) and data type int32
```

Comment: do you get a traceback?

Comment: How many nonzero values are there in `C`?  You can check `C.nnz`.

Comment: I updated my message error ```idx``` is a numpy array I use to construct the sparse matrix (positions of the nonzero values), but there is more to the story that's why I don't include the previous code. My nonzero values are ```57012620```

Comment: It looks like it is trying to create a CSR matrix with 152087117507 nonzero entries.  The product `Ct*C` has shape (28508141, 28508141),  so that number of nonzero values corresponds to a density of about 2e-4.  It is sparse, but the result still has a huge number of nonzero values that have to be stored.

Comment: Ok, so how do you deal with this problem? Because is an important step for my project

Comment: Is it possible to allocate more memory ?

Comment: How to deal  with it depends on what you are going to do with the result.  For example, you might be able to work in batches, in which you iteratively compute subsets of the product.  This only works if the next step in your analysis can compute its result when it only sees one part of the input at a time.  But this is getting out of scope for stackoverflow (and definitely out of scope for the comments in SO); [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) might be a better forum for such a discussion.

Comment: The `csr` matrix will also require a `data` array of the Terabyte size.  The `indptr` array will be smaller, only (28508142,).

Comment: Ok I agree, but what's  the conclusion?

Comment: The conclusion is that the problem is with your project. You have an intermediate data structure that requires 2.5 TB of memory to hold. You can either learn to work at that scale (and there are options, but they effectively consist of a new skill set), or you can redesign your project so you don't need this data structure (perhaps by batching it and processing in smaller groups).

Comment: Is it possible to store the product on the disk then use it ?

Comment: I can save ```np.savez('file.npz', data=C.data, indices=C.indices, indptr=C.indptr, shape=C.shape)``` information for one array like that but I don't know if there is a light somewhere. Because I am hoping if can do the operation with ```np.memmap``` somehow.

Comment: Because at this end I just want the positions (row,col) of the nonzero elements of this product.

Comment: Why? Can you do your downstream analysis on, say, a row of the product, then throw it away and calculate the next row, do the downstream analysis, etc?

Answer (score -1):

For future viewers who want to multiply **huge** sparse matrices I solved my problem using *PyTables* and saved the result of the multiplication in chunks. Still it creates a big file but at least is compressed. The code I used goes like this:

```
import tables as tb

f = tb.open_file('D:\dot.h5', 'w')
l, m, n = Ct.shape[0], Ct.shape[1], C.shape[1]
filters = tb.Filters(complevel=8, complib='blosc')
out_data = f.create_earray(f.root, 'data', tb.Int32Atom(), shape=(0,), filters=filters)
out_indices = f.create_earray(f.root, 'indices', tb.Int32Atom(),shape=(0,), filters=filters)
out_indptr = f.create_earray(f.root, 'indptr', tb.Int32Atom(), shape=(0,), filters=filters)
out_indptr.append(np.array([0])) #this is needed as a first indptr
max_indptr = 0
#buffersize
bl = 10000
for i in range(0, l, bl):
 res = Ct[i:min(i+bl, l),:].dot(C)
 out_data.append(res.data)
 indices = res.indices
 indptr = res.indptr
 out_indices.append(indices)
 out_indptr.append(max_indptr+indptr[1:])
 max_indptr += indices.shape[0]
```

So if for example you want access to the 2nd row of your final matrix you simply can:

```
L2 = csr_matrix((a.data[a.indptr[2]:a.indptr[2+1]], a.indices[a.indptr[2]:a.indptr[2+1]], np.array([0,len(a.indices[a.indptr[2]:a.indptr[2+1]])])), shape=(1,n))
```